# WPF DataGrid TemplateColumn Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

WPF newbie here

I want to display a [datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=net-5.0), where the user can edit text in a cell AND interact with buttons.
The Idea is that a list of items (e.g 2 Items with category a and 1 Item with category b)gets converted to a string with numbers (e.g 2a1b). Two Buttons (+ and -) increase/decrease the last entry (e.g 2a2b), but the logic of that is not important to the question.

[Picture of Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj5sY.png)

In the ViewModel, the list of rows is initialized and the DataGrid uses this list as ItemsSource

---

```cs
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Header}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mon" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MenuSelectionTableCellTemplate}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tue" Binding="{Binding Items.Tue}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wed" Binding="{Binding Items.Wed}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thu" Binding="{Binding Items.Thu}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fri" Binding="{Binding Items.Fri}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sat" Binding="{Binding Items.Sat}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

The Cell template looks like this:

```cs
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuSelectionTableCellTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="34" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="?"/>
    <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="?" />
    <Button Content="-" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="?" />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

It would be nice to be able to "give" the template the string to insert in the TextBox and the two button handlers, or ab object that has these three things.

Comment: I think you will need a bidirectional converter that will receive the required string from the collection item and vice versa, change the values in the collection item based on the received string.
Bind the Text property to the current context through this converter.

Comment: For buttons it is better to use commands.
But if you still want to leave the Click handlers, then you need to get the button from sender in them.
And from its DataContext property get the collection item.
And then in this element, change the values in the way you need.